# How do I add a pop-up success/fail message that is based on time?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, onsubmit

I have a submit button on my forms:

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-lg" name="Submit" onclick="javascript:FormRequest();">Submit</button>
<input type="hidden" name="txthiddenjson" id="txthiddenjson" />
```

and the FormRequest() function:

```
function FormRequest() 
{
    var formData = form2js('JsonForm', '.', false, "", "", true);
    document.getElementById('txthiddenjson').value = JSON.stringify(formData, null, '\t'); 
{
```

The question I have is, how do I add a pop-up message after the user clicks "Submit" that will:

1. Display a Success message if the submission takes less than 5
   seconds
2. Display a Fail message if the submission takes more than 5 seconds
3. Have the dialogue box disappear immediately after displaying the message, and allow the post to either submit successfully or go back to the blank form if it is a failure, and have the user re-try the submission.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: When posting back to the server, you can pass back a success or error message to your page which you can use to determine what message to show the user

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using web forms or MVC?

Comment: I am using MVC for this solution

Comment: You could add properties to your View Model of SuccessMessage and ErrorMessage then when you return your model to the View, check those propertie s to see if you should display success or error.